# How to conditionally hide a border at any view breakpoint below "large" in bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a column (inside a row) that has a special border like so

```
.foo-bar {
    border-left: 4px solid red;
}
```

This looks great at the "full" view but when it starts "stacking" (med/small viewport) I'd like to hide this border. What is the idiomatic way to do this w/ bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LESS:

```
.foo-bar {
    border-left: 4px solid red;
    @media (max-width:@screen-lg-min){
    border-left:none;
    }
}
```

In CSS

```
 .foo-bar {
        border-left: 4px solid red;
  }
  @media (max-width:1199px){
        .foo-bar{
        border-left:none;
        }
  }
```

Max width in CSS is whatever your lg breakpoint is set to.

Comment: I think by idiomatic he means native boostrap (no additional CSS/media queries).

Comment: Well, then your answer would work, but it would need to be duplicated content (or done with matchmedia or the like).

Comment: Yeah I agree - would have to write out the <div> twice.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 is mobile first, so you need first declare styles for extra small resolution, then add border-left:

```
@screen-sm-min: 768px;

.foo-bar {
  border-left-color: red;
  border-left-style: solid;
}
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
  .foo-bar {
    border-left-width: 4px;
  }
}
```